# Windows Phone ListBox Selector With Click Left

Tags: windows-phone-8, listbox, windows-phone, selection, longlistselector

Which component provide us opening multiselection menu with checkboxes via click empty part on left or clicking "Select" button on appbar?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

You need to install Windows Phone Toolkit from Nuget Package Manager to have this element. This is `LongListMultiSelector`. This is not found in the default elements in the WP8 SDK. Use the following instructions.

[Installing Windows Phone Toolkit](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/how-to-install-windows-phone-toolkit---october-2012--8-0-sdk--via-nuget)

[Using Windows Phone Toolkit](http://www.davidsalter.com/2013/09/using-the-windows-phone-toolkit-in-wp8-applications.html)

After installing the WPTookit follow the bellow instructions.

you can enable selection mode by either taping on the empty area of the left side or by pressing a button. If you use a button you can add the following code to enable the selection mode..

```
private void btnEnableSelect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    llms.EnforceIsSelectionEnabled = true;
}
```

You can use `IsSelectionEnabledChanged` event to detect when the selection mode is enable/disabled.

```
llms.IsSelectionEnabledChanged += llms_IsSelectionEnabledChanged;

void llms_IsSelectionEnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // your task here...
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but are you talking about Windows Phone 8? There aren't EnforceIsSelectionEnabled property in Listbox or LongListSelector.

Comment: Yes, This is WP8 but you will not have this Multi Select capability in WP8 right of the bat. You need to have Windows Phone Toolkit installed to use LongListMultiSelector. This is not ordinary ListBox or LongListSelector.. This is LongListMultiSelector. use Nuget Package Manager to install. Search as WPToolkit